# Is there a ProgramData equivalent for OS X/macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries

In Windows, it's common to write shared data to `%ProgramData%\path\to\stuff`. From there, programs installed for any user can access it as a sort of "source of truth" or common repository. Usually writing to this directory is a low-privilege operation, unlike writing to `%ProgramFiles%`.

What's the right thing to do for data meant to be used for one or more users in OS X/Sierra? Preferably without privilege escalation?

Context is third-party pkg installer, not a sandboxed app.

Comment: The answer may depend on whether you're creating a sandboxed (App Store) app or not.

Comment: Oh, good call, will edit the question.